# Why is Fiona giving me a error while importing Geopandas?

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas, fiona

I receive the following error while importing Geopandas! Can someone let me know what the issue is?

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  
File "/Users/nischalkashyap/Downloads/Fall 2020/Research Assistant 
GIS/database/geopandas/geopandas/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  
from geopandas.io.file import _read_file as read_file  # noqa
 
File "/Users/nischalkashyap/Downloads/Fall 2020/Research Assistant 
GIS/database/geopandas/geopandas/io/file.py", line 7, in <module>
  
  import fiona
  File "/Users/nischalkashyap/Downloads/virtual_env_python/sr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Fiona-2.0.dev0-py3.9-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/fiona/__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
    from fiona.collection import BytesCollection, Collection
  File "/Users/nischalkashyap/Downloads/virtual_env_python/sr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Fiona-2.0.dev0-py3.9-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/fiona/collection.py", line 9, in <module>
    from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
  File "fiona/ogrext.pyx", line 1, in init fiona.ogrext
ImportError:
dlopen(/Users/nischalkashyap/Downloads/virtual_env_python/sr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Fiona-2.0.dev0-py3.9-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/fiona/_shim.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): 
Symbol not found: _OSRFixup
  
Referenced from: /Users/nischalkashyap/Downloads/virtual_env_python/sr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Fiona-2.0.dev0-py3.9-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/fiona/_shim.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/nischalkashyap/Downloads/virtual_env_python/sr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Fiona-2.0.dev0-py3.9-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/fiona/_shim.cpython-39-darwin.so
```

Comment: GIS packages are notoriously tricky to install. The most reliable method that I've found is to use conda, create a fresh environment, and install everything from the conda-forge channel

Comment: Better use `conda` environment in windows. Its handy  and wont make any mess. Go for Anaconda, with spyder.,maybe your problem will be solved